# height of 2 rows and 2 merged rows using div

Tags: css, html, row-height

Basically I want to achieve this using DIV:

```
---------------
|one   |       |
|------| three |
|two   |       |
----------------
```

where height of 'three' matches height of 'one' and 'two'.

The code I have:

```
<div class="detail-main">
    <div class="detail-leftcol">
        <div class="detail-one">
            This is One         
                       </div>
        <div class="detail-two">
            This is Two
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="detail-three">
        This is Three
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.detail-main    {
     position:relative;
     width:500px;
}

div.detail-leftcol
{    
    float:left;    
    width:250px;
}

div.detail-one    {
    border: thin solid;
    margin-bottom:2.5px;
}

div.detail-two    {
    border: thin solid;
    margin-bottom:2.5px;
}

div.detail-three    {
    border: thin solid;
    float:right;
    width:245px;
    margin-left:2.5px;
}
```

The result I'm getting is this:

```
|-----------------|
|One     | Three  |
|------------------
|Two     |
----------
```

What should be changed to Three to be in line with height of One and Two put together?

Help would be great!

Comment: So many divs and it looks like tabular data - maybe you could use a html table for that?

Comment: I had a problem with tables before where if I hide/show certain tr or td using javascript, it will create some blank spaces in between elements. WHen I used DIVs, it solved that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="one">one</div>
    <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
<div class="three">one</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left, .three{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
}
.three{background:red;}
.left > div{
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}
.left .two{background:blue}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/suNUK/4/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and it works great in CHrome and Firefox but not in IE8, where it shows those 3 elements in 3 rows. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm not too sure why but I just cannot get it working in IE8. those 3 cells are in 3 different rows :(

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your markup you can use jQuery like this:

```
var detail1Height = $(".detail-one").outerHeight();
var detail2Height = $(".detail-two").outerHeight();

$(".detail-three").height(detail1Height + detail2Height + 1);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/M4tpx/

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for attempt. and I'm sure it will work with javascript but i'm looking for styling with just CSS at the moment. Sorry, I was not specific in my details.